# In the nhibernate, how can I determine if a mapped entity has cascade = "all"?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm making a general nhibernate method that can determine, given an instantiated nhibernate mapped object at runtime, if that object is referenced by some other object in the 'database'.

This way, I'll be able to allow the user to delete objects if they are not referenced, and throw errors if they are (along with some info about how many things reference the object).

I ran into a snag though, when an entity is mapped cascade = all, I want them to be able to delete this thing even though other objects reference it.

So, I just need to know how I can use the Nhibernate.MetaData.IClassMetaData to determine if an 'entity type' or bag is cascade = all. I can't seem to find it after looking for a few minutes.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Isaac

P.S. here is the method code (unfinished). IDomainObject just makes sure the passed object has an int ID property.

```
public int getReferenceCount<T>(T objectToCheck) where T : Interfaces.IDomainObject
    {   
        Type objectType = typeof(T);
        string className = objectType.Name;
        IDictionary<string, NHibernate.Metadata.IClassMetadata> myDictionary = session.SessionFactory.GetAllClassMetadata();
        int referenceCount = 0;
        string fullClassName = objectType.FullName;
        foreach (var thisClassPair in myDictionary)
        {
            NHibernate.Metadata.IClassMetadata thisClass = thisClassPair.Value;
            for (int i = 0; i < thisClass.PropertyTypes.Length; i++)
            {

                string propertyName;
                if (thisClass.PropertyTypes[i].Name == fullClassName)
                {
                    if (thisClass.PropertyTypes[i] is NHibernate.Type.ManyToOneType || thisClass.PropertyTypes[i] is NHibernate.Type.OneToOneType)
                    {
                        propertyName = thisClass.PropertyNames[i];
                        List<object> results = this.HQLQuery<object>("from " + thisClassPair.Key + " as refClass where refClass."+propertyName+".id = '"+objectToCheck.ID+"'"); 

                    }
                }


            }

        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just let them try to delete the object (int try block) and if error occurs, show them that object is referenced. Maintaining data integrity is the job of the database, that's why FK's are needed.

Comment: I can't because the delete's get added to a transaction which is then put though when they hit the save button. This way they don't have to wait until they save to find out something went wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var persister = (NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister)thisClass;
var cascadeStyle = persister.GetCascadeStyle(i);
```